# What does the message ' do not match any available overloads' mean?

Tags: ios, swift, random, gamekit

In the playground, I'm trying to generate random numbers for a normal distribution using the following code:

```
import UIKit
import GameplayKit

var mu: Double = 0
var random: Double = 0

for i in 1...1000 {
    let random = GKRandomSource()
    mu = GKGaussianDistribution(randomSource: random, mean: Float(0.0), distribution: Float(1.0))
    print(mu)
}
```

This will not compile, I get the following error message: "Argument labels '(randomSource:, mean:, distribution:)' do not match any available overloads"

What does this mean and how can I correct the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code, the parameter is called `deviation`, not `distribution`, and the Distribution object itself does not return a random number.

Try this instead:

```
import GameplayKit
let random = GKRandomSource()
let dist = GKGaussianDistribution(randomSource: random, mean: 0, deviation: 1.0)

for _ in 1...1000 {
    let mu = dist.nextUniform()
    print(mu)
}
```